# SIP Mobicents - How to create new Request in a existing dialog? (Same Call-ID)

Tags: java, sip

I'm currently developing a communication-system with sip, using mobicents (sip-servlet implementation on tomcat) as basis. I tryed to implement a Notification-Service, where UAs can subscribe to get Status-Info via Notify from time to time. As I read in RFC3265-"Specific Event Notification" the NOTIFY-Messages of the Subscription must have the same Call-ID because they belong to the Subscribe-Dialog.

Problem: Now I have problems with creating NOTIFYs with the same Call-ID, because I have no idea how to tell the servlet-container that the new request belongs to a current dialog.
This is what I tryed for testing:

```
public void doSubscribe(SipServletRequest request){
    try{
        //Get Session
        SipApplicationSession session = request.getApplicationSession();

        //Send response
        SipServletResponse response = request.createResponse(SipServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.setExpires(600);
        response.setHeader("Event", "buddylist");
        response.send();

        //Send notify (same call-id!!!)
        Address serverAddress = this.sipFactory.createAddress("sip:server@test.com");
        SipServletRequest newRequest  = sipFactory.createRequest(session, "NOTIFY", serverAddress, request.getFrom());
        newRequest.setHeader("Subscription-State", "active;expires=600");
        newRequest.setHeader("Event", "buddylist");
        newRequest.send();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

I thought adding the same session would do the job, but it doesn't. Does anyone know how to do this right?

Answer (score 1):

it took quite some time but I figured it out myself. Seems like I misunderstood the creation of new requests via the SipFactory in combination with the SipApplicationSession.

My current point of view (hope it is correct this time):
The SipFactory is used to create initial Requests for a complete new Dialog, and only for new Dialogs. Whereas the SipApplicationSession is just a Container which stores the Session-Objects for every new Session.
That means, that the code above created a second SipSession in the SipApplicationSession-Container, which was independent from the SipSession which was created by the incomming SUBSCRIBE-Request!
To create a Request in a existing Dialog you have to use the SipSession-Object itself:

```
    public void doSubscribe(SipServletRequest request){
        try{
            //Get !!!SipSession
            SipSession sipSession = request.getSession();

            //Send response
            SipServletResponse response = request.createResponse(SipServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.setExpires(600);
            response.setHeader("Event", "buddylist");
            response.send();

            //Send notify (same call-id!!!)
            SipServletRequest newRequest  = sipSession.createRequest("NOTIFY");
            newRequest.setHeader("Subscription-State", "active;expires=600");
            newRequest.setHeader("Event", "buddylist");
            newRequest.send();
         } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }       
   }
```

Well in the end the solution was simple. But there are less examples or documentations which help you to understand something like this. Therefore I hope this helps everyone facing the same problems as me.